# how to configure live server extension in vscode linux to open new instance in already open browser window

Tags: visual-studio-code, web-deployment, ubuntu-18.04, html-rendering

i am trying to configure my visual studio code(installed on ubuntu 18.04 LTS). i use [live server extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) developed by [ritwick dey](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/publishers/ritwickdey) to render my web page dynamically. but every time i run live server extension, it opens a new window of firefox (my default browser) that it attaches with visual studio code as a new window. But i want the live server(extension) to open a new tab in the already open browser window. I remember that in windows 10 OS live server opens a new tab in already open browser window. Is there any workaround that i can do to achieve the same result ?

here is [my vscode settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERYjw.png) that i use globally. and here is the [source code of live-server extension.](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server)

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear what you really need, when I open it, I open it in a new tab in the same browser, but if you need the server to update automatically, in my case I uninstalled it and installed it again in VScode, copy to estencion ext install ritwickdey.liveserver and it worked for me. I hope it helps you brother.

chek
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/205293/configurar-extencion-live-server-de-vs-code

Answer (score 0):

it happened with me also. In my case i have downloaded it from snap store and that issue happened but when i installed through external .deb file, it worked.